# JQuery - show certain amount of DIVs according to drop down selection

Tags: jquery, html, show

I gotta need help on this.

I'm not an expert in JQUERY but I want to show a certain amount of div boxes according to the selection drop down with a list of numbers in it. My code isn't working for some reason. Please advise me on where I did wrong. Thanks in advance! :)

Below is my HTML:

```
<select id="dropDown">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<div id="box-container" class="boxes">
  <div id="1" class="box"></div>
  <div id="2" class="box"></div>
  <div id="3" class="box"></div>
  <div id="4" class="box"></div>
  <div id="5" class="box"></div>
  <div id="6" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Below is my JQUERY:

```
$('#dropDown').change(function(){
    if ($('#dropDown').val() = '0')
    {

    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '1')
    {
        $('#1').show();
    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '2')
    {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').show();
    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '3')
    {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').show();
        $('#3').show();
    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '4')
    {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').show();
        $('#3').show();
        $('#4').show();
    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '5')
    {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').show();
        $('#3').show();
        $('#4').show();
        $('#5').show();
    }
    else if ($('#dropDown').val() = '6')
    {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#2').show();
        $('#3').show();
        $('#4').show();
        $('#5').show();
        $('#6').show();

    }
});
```

And this is the CSS for the divs:

```
.boxes div {
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a quick demo of this working, if you have any questions feel free to ask me. It's fairly straight forward and I've tried to make the code verbose to aid understanding.

http://codepen.io/Leth0_/pen/HiruJ

```
$("#dropDown").change(function(){
  var x = parseInt($(this).val());
  var element = $("#box-container").children();
  $(element).css({display:"none"});
  for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
    $(element[i]).css({display:"block"});
    }
});
```

Comment: No problem, I added comments to the code in the demo to explain each stage :). Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained comments! Helps alot! =D

Answer (score 1):

Your attempting:

```
if ($('#dropDown').val() = 0) {
```

What you want to do is:

```
if ($('#dropDown').val() == 0) { ... etc
```

When you use '=', this assigns a value to a variable of some sort. The '==' is used for comparison so this is what you want to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after the `change` line:

```
var value = $('#dropDown').val();
```

And then use these on if and else statements like such:

```
if (value == '1')
```

**Note: Use two `=` instead of one :)**

`=` is used to assign a value to a variable.

`==` is used for comparison.

Also I don't think you need the `if` statement for `value == "0"` so you can just remove it. Keep your code clean!

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/34gC7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you should be using "==" not "=" in your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#dropDown').change(function(){
     $(".box").hide();
     for(var i=1;i<=parseInt($(this).val());i++){
          $("#"+i).show();
     }
});
```

I wouldn't use a number as the id though.